# toCharArray and replace detected in an index

Tags: java

I have here two problems needed to be solved. First off: I have here my program, wherein I want that whatever the user inputs will be saved on a string, and to be placed in an array.

my codes:

```
String words;
    String replaced_words;

    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a line of words basing on an event, verse, place or a name of a person.");
        words = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Word accepted!");
        //using char array method
        char [] c = words.toCharArray();
```

Now, I used the replace method for the string such as this:

```
String replace = words.replace(' ', '-');
```

But the problem is, this occurs as an error. By replacing the ' ' character into words such as:

```
String replace = words.replace(words, '-')
```

although I want to limit the length of the hyphens depending on the numbers of characters on the words.

The output of this program should be the following:
· Create a copy of this string to an array where each letter is replaced with a hyphen (-) and each space is replaced with an underscore (_). Symbols and numbers will remain shown.

The problems I'm getting is that it doesn't replace them with a hyphen and underscore. It just displays the inputted text I did just typed via scanner.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is your input, and expected output? Please post all relevant details while asking questions.

Comment: let me add that on my post...okay wait.

Comment: show us how you do the output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but `words.replace(words, '-')` will replace the entire string with a single `-`

Comment: how can i make it be replaced with equal to the length of the array?

Comment: `words.replaceAll(".", "-");`. In a regular expression, a `.` means any character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use:

```
    String word = "AB CD EF";
    String replace = word.replace(' ' , '-').replaceAll("[^\\-]", "_");
    System.out.println(replace); // prints "__-__-__"
```

if you want spaces between the underscores (to distinguish them from each other) you can use

```
    for (int i = 0; i < replace.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(replace.charAt(i) + " ");
    }
    // prints "_ _ - _ _ - _ _ "
```

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to know each of the character's index so when I place them like in Hangman, it'd show the correct guesses?

Comment: Look at [indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) method of class String.

Comment: okay, i'll look to that now. Hope I can finish this program / mini game.